# Reassign variable in numerous modules?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, architecture, modularity

I have a variable `let activeNode;` in `main.js`. It can be changed by either keyboard input or mouse input. The functions dealing with each are modularized into their own files `keyboard.js` and `mouse.js`. activeNode is exported into these modules.

Whenever the functions attempt to reassign the imported variable `activeNode`, console logs the error `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

I've seen other answers saying to also create and export a function `updateVariable(var)` in `main.js` and then call it in the modules to reassign `activeNode`, but I'd prefer not having to create an export and entire function just to reassign a variable.

Is there any other way to accomplish cross-module reassignment of variables? (And without having to pass the variable into the module function calls, because the mouse input function calls are deeply nested in main.js and I don't want to have to tunnel a parameter through a bunch of higher level functions.)

Comment: Can you share a code example ?

Comment: keyboard.js has function that when key input happens, activeNode is reassigned to a new value. Same with mouse.js. It's just a variable in main.js, that is being exported into two modules, with those two modules attempting to reassign the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done "serious" Javascript programming for about a million years, so my answer will be more general and not state of the art.

@Saran Surya is right - code examples would help here, we can't see *how* you are doing what you are doing.

`Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable` will occur if you do this `if(x = y)` when you meant `if(x == y)`   Reminds me I once spent a hour trying to debug an error which turned out to be `If(x == y)`  (capital i) - the moral of that story is that the cause of the error might be a lot more basic than you think.

Another possibility you haven't accidentally declared something as `const` have you?

Or, have you declared the variable but not initialized it (when it gets called by mouse/keyboard)?

Changing tack, just declare `activeNode` as a global variable?

Alternatively, one approach is using separate main/keyboard/mouse **classes**, simply expose activeNode as a public field on the `main` class.

```
class main{
  activeNode = '';
}

class mouse{
  DoSomethingMousey(){
    main.activeNode = 'I am a mouse';
  }
}
```